# Removing bootstrap Modal from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a piece of code to load part of my content dynamically after user triggers the event by clicking.

Case Scenario is: when user clicks on the post, it will open a `modal` and display the detailed view which is the dynamic generated content using the `slug` in the link. However, I need to remove the modal from the `DOM` when user closes the `modal`. for now i have only been able to `hide` it but I need to remove it.

here is my code.

**PHP Laravel HTML Markup ():**

```
<div class="content-blocks blog hidex">

        <section class="content">
            <div class="block-content">
                <h3 class="block-title">My Blog</h3>
                <div id="post-list" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                    {% set posts = blogPosts.posts %}

                    {% for post in posts %}
                    <div class="post">

                        <div class="post-thumbnail">
                            {% if post.featured_images.count %}
                            {% set image = post.featured_images|first %}
                            <a class="open-post" href="{{'blog-post'|page}}">
                                <img
                                        data-src="{{ image.filename }}"
                                        src="{{ image.path }}"
                                        alt="{{ image.description }}"
                                        style="max-width: 100%"/>

                            </a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-title">
                            <a class="open-post" href="{{ post.url }}"><h2>{{ post.title }}</h2></a>
                            <p class="post-info">


                                <span class="post-author">Posted by {{ post.user.first_name}} </span>
                                <span class="slash"></span>
                                <span class="post-date">on {{ post.published_at|date('M d, Y') }}</span>
                                <span class="slash"></span>
                                {% if post.categories.count %} in {% endif %}
                                {% for category in post.categories %}
                                <span class="post-category">{{ category.name }}</span>
                                {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-body">
                            <p>{{ post.summary }}</p>
                            <a class="btn open-post" href="{{ post.url }}">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <div class="text-center">
                        {% if posts.lastPage > 1 %}
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            {% if posts.currentPage > 1 %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage-1) }) }}"
                                   aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                </a></li>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% for page in 1..posts.lastPage %}
                            <li class="{{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                                <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}

                            {% if posts.lastPage > posts.currentPage %}
                            <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage+1) }) }}"
                                   aria-label="Next">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                            </a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//Blog post Modal
    $('.open-post').on('click', function(){
        var postUrl = $(this).attr("href");

        var post = '<div class="modal" id="post-modal"><div class="inline-menu-container"><a id="modal-close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a></div><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"></div></div></div>';

        $(post).modal({
          remote: postUrl
        })

        return false;
    });
// close the modal
   $('#close').on( 'click', function() {
      $('.name-block').removeClass('reverse');
      $('.name-block-container').removeClass('reverse');
      $('.menu-blocks').removeClass('hidex');
      $('.content-blocks').removeClass('showx');
      $('.content-blocks').addClass('hidex');
      $('.inline-menu-container').removeClass('showx');
      $('.inline-menu-container').addClass('hidex');
      $('.menu-item').removeClass('active');
    });
```

**result of Javascript code in the DOM:**

```
<div class="modal in" id="post-modal" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">
    <div class="inline-menu-container">
    <a id="modal-close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></a>
</div>
<div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   /// all the dynamic content in the modal
   </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to remove this result without refreshing the page.
**Update:**
This is how it looks in the HTML in Inspect after closing the `modal`:
[image]

**Note:** 
I tried to remove the modal content from the DOM using the `#post-modal` id but wasn't successful. also, i haven't been able to find an example of using `Delegate` while the modal elements and content are completely added by javascript after loading the 'DOM'.

Comment: why don't you try with css? `.modal-dialog{ display: none !important; }`

Comment: @I.G.Pascual I have a JQuery Sildeshow in the modal that throws an exception whenever I open the page for the second time because of multiple elements in the DOM. so i need to remove the modal from DOM.

Comment: then javascript is the answer

Comment: @I.G.Pascual thats where I'm having trouble with delegating the modal to it's parent element as it's completely added to the DOM by JS. i tried using `$('Document').on('click','blog-post'function())... as parent and still no luck.

Comment: have you tried `$(function(){ $("#post-modal").remove(); $(".modal-dialog").remove(); });`?

Comment: @I.G.Pascual I used your function like  `$(document)
     .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $("#post-modal").remove(); $(".modal-dialog").remove(); });` and it worked

Comment: Nice! Glad it worked

Comment: @I.G.Pascual  thanks for all the help. would you like to post it as the answer or should i do it myself  ?

Comment: You can do it yourself an accept it if you like. I will be thankful enough if you just reference my comment on the answer ^_^. You could also give credit to @SergChernata as he introduced the idea of listening `hidden.bs.modal` event. Good job btw!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [I.G. Pascual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443310/i-g-pascual) and [Serg Chernata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233337/serg-chernata) here is the solution:

**Javascript code:**

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $("#post-modal").remove(); $(".modal-dialog").remove(); });
```

Answer (score 5):

[Bind an event](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) and then [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

or

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal').remove();
});
```

Comment: quick question. I have tried this before like this $('#blog-post').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).remove();
}); but didn't work. can you tell me which Id should i use for #myModal as I'm adding the whole modal to the DOM with JS as i explained in the post

Comment: I tried that and it didn't remove the modal from the DOM. i added an image of the Inspect to make it more clear. the Image shows the code after closing the modal by hiding it. i also added the JS code i use in JS.

Comment: You have more than one modal with that id. It's probably working but removing the third...OR it's not working at all due to multiple id's.

Comment: that's exactly why i am looking for a way to remove it instead of hiding it. these multiple modals are created because I only hide them and not remove them. I uploaded the image to show what happening and how to solve

Comment: Weird, then use class. Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that as well. but no luck. weird thing is that i can see that `$(document)
     .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open') })` in modal.js is working and remove the class from body but in my main JS it's not working. can it be `delegate` issue even though im using `hidden.bs.modal`. im not sure if it sees the modal element as it's added dynamically

Comment: Is this live somewhere? I don't think I can help you any further otherwise.

Comment: i solved it by using a suggestion in comments like this '$(document)
     .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $("#post-modal").remove(); $(".modal-dialog").remove(); });' thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$(modal).modal().on('hidden.bs.modal',function(e){
    e.target.remove();
})
```

you can directly add the hidden event on the initialization itself. so you don't have to trigger separately each time.

Answer (score 0):

Below given snippet will show you how can you do something that you want without having to do anything extra and also by not even writing conventional bootstrap modal code.

For further reference you can also visit [this link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/). It will show you how you can create modal dynamically with minimum efforts.

```js
function open_modal(name) {

  var message = $('#frm_1');
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'New message to ' + name,
    message: $('#frm_1'),
    onshown: function() {
      $('#recipient-name').val(name);
    },
    onhide: function(dialog) {
      console.log('Cerrada');
      $('#hidden-div').append(message);
    },
    buttons: [{
      label: 'Close',
      action: function(dialog) {
        dialog.close();
      }
    }, {
      label: 'Send message',
      cssClass: 'btn btn-primary',
      action: function(dialog) {
        // Do whatever send message does, here
      }
    }]
  });



}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="open_modal('@mdo')">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="open_modal('@fat')">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="open_modal('@getbootstrap')">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>


<div id="hidden-div" style="display : none">

  <form id="frm_1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```